# how to count and field name from this query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT publisher, Count(publisher) 
FROM (SELECT NULL author, title, NULL journal, publisher, NULL abstracts, keyword, subject 
       FROM   dental) AS one 
WHERE ( author LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR title LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR subject LIKE '%Bastone%' ) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT author, title, journal, publisher, abstracts, keyword, NULL subject 
        FROM   wiley) AS one 
WHERE ( author LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR title LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR subject LIKE '%Bastone%' ) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT author, title, journal, publisher, abstracts, keyword, NULL subject 
        FROM   sage) AS one 
WHERE ( author LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR title LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR subject LIKE '%Bastone%' ) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT author, title, journal, publisher, abstracts, keyword, NULL subject 
        FROM   elsevier) AS one 
WHERE ( author LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR title LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR subject LIKE '%Bastone%' ) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM  (SELECT author, title, journal, publisher, abstracts, keyword, NULL subject 
        FROM   indianjournal) AS one 
WHERE ( author LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR title LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR journal LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' 
          OR subject LIKE '%Bastone%' ) 
GROUP  BY publisher
```

But i am getting error from sql when m executing it. So please help me regarding this how to get count and field name through this query

**error what i am getting is :**

> #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: What is this dude? Align the code properly.

Comment: srry fo this mistake but there is any solution ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 errors in your statement 1) - first select is different to all the other selects - I suggest you make it the same 2) a closing parenthesis is required before the group by 3) the sub query needs an alias 
The following tests ok

```
SELECT Publisher,COUNT(Publisher) 
FROM
(
select * from (SELECT NULL author, Title, NULL journal, publisher, NULL abstracts, keyword, subject FROM dental) AS one 
WHERE (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Title LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Subject LIKE '%Bastone%') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT author, title, journal, publisher, abstracts, keyword, NULL subject FROM wiley) AS one 
WHERE (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Title LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Subject LIKE '%Bastone%') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT author, title, journal, publisher, abstracts, keyword, NULL subject FROM sage) AS one 
WHERE (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Title LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Subject LIKE '%Bastone%') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT author, title, journal, publisher, abstracts, keyword, NULL subject FROM elsevier) AS one 
WHERE (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Title LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Subject LIKE '%Bastone%') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT author, title, journal, publisher, abstracts, keyword, NULL subject FROM indianjournal) AS one 
WHERE (Author LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Title LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Journal LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Publisher LIKE '%Bastone%' 
OR abstracts LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Keyword LIKE '%Bastone%' OR Subject LIKE '%Bastone%') 
) s
GROUP BY Publisher
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query ( if you want, but I think will be very slow in real-conditions, any way.. ).
If you want to count the rezult of Publisher, remove the COUNT() from the query, and after the query in your PHP script, use count() php function, just to count the array of return result.

***PSEUDO CODE:***

```
$query = 'SELECT ... ';
$return_result = mysqli_query($query);

$count = count($return_result);
```

Comment: could you please send me the structure ??

Comment: just where is my $query, use your query string, and after that execute the query, or if you want in the query you can use COUNT(Publisher) as count_publisher, and after that when rendering the result use count_publisher to show the count, it's give a virtual name for that, like real column in the database.